# Who dropped all the tables in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, webserver

The tables in the database i use for my website was dropped in some way. I didn't do it, but i don't know who did it. My hosting company says we didn't do either. So is there a way to know who did it? If there is a solution for it, i'll be grateful. My website is offline now.

Thanks

Comment: Of course you have backups correct? No, there is no way of finding out who done this unless you have full logging enabled, which is unlikely. Even then, I am not sure it will give you that information.

Comment: If you were using it using An Application in which your code was exposed, then it is very easy for anyone to go there and drop the tables. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you do not have a backup: as Stanley has pointed out, your code might have been vulnerable. This is just one out of many possible solutions.

Small checklist:

- Check whether the DB is accessible from outside localhost (usually it should not)
- Check password security
- Check who has access to your DB and whether you can trust them
- Check your code for SQL injection vulnerability: [What is SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Comment: I checked the list but the only possibility is sql injection, i'll check it again, thanks